# TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect - node can't get data from mysql when are in docker compose

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect node with mysql through dokcer-compose. I can access mysql with workbench but when I try to connect with node I get the error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js: 1054: 14))
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  #App Service
  app:
    image: "node:alpine"
    container_name: cms-node
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    ports:
      - 1234:1234
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db

  #Mysql Service
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: cms-mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    # command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: CMS
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

#### node create connection

```
const db: Connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'CMS',
});

export default db;
```

#### node try to connect

```
db.connect((err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log('Connected!');
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the link name (by default, the name of the linked service) as the hostname to connect to. See the [docker-compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) documentation for details.

So just use `host: 'db'` instead of `host: 'localhost'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have to use service name from `docker-compose.yml`. I faced a similar issue when there was a custom front end API Gateway server (*working as proxy*) written in `node.js` connecting to other two services. So replacing `localhost:3001` with `serviceName:30001` fixed the issue.

Example code:

```
...
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
...

app.use('/json-parser', proxy('json_parsing_api:3001'));
app.get('/json-parser/json-to-person', proxy('json-to-person'));
```